# program starting GUI login on Fedora (23)

Tags: linux, fedora

do you know what starts GUI to log in Fedora 23 or what package(s) must be installed to enable GUI login? It worked at the beginning but after some clean up I've done, it doesn't work any more. I can only login the system in text mode and using `startx` launch the graphic interface (but not the one I'd like to work in). Or how to get info regarding what has felt when the system was loading? Supposed to be now `journalctl ???`

ok, try to formulate it with more detailed description.

On a workstation (laptop or desktop) it is usually possible to login in and start to work in graphical environment in 2 ways:

1. command prompt login, then execute `startx`
2. a program launches as soon as the system is loaded with draws a nice looking graphical boxes with names of users registered in the system and a menu where it is possible to select which desktop environment the user would like to work in. It's all in graphic. As soon as a user name and the password are provided the system loads the user preferable GUI

I can't login using the way 2. I don't know the name of the program, which draws graphical windows for login.

I see way 1 as a way around the problem. And after some manual changes in Xsession and Xclients I managed to switch from default gnome DE to my preferable one - cinnamon.

GDM starts user's preferable or default DE *after* login. But the login itself can be either text or graphic. I can't get graphic login interface.

The issue is not crucial since there is a way around, pointed as way 1 above.

Comment: what clean up did you perform? what GUI do you get with startx if you say it is not the one you would like to work in? check your history and undo the cleaning.

Comment: What you want is a display manager, e.g. gdm.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @fixer1234 cinnamon. Now I can start it by startx

Comment: Startx starts the GUI system, but as Tom Yan mentioned, the specific program that handles login is the display manager.  The DM is typically part of the desktop (GDM for Gnome, KDM for KDE, etc.)  Cinnamon is a Mint product, and I believe the default DM for Cinnamon is the Mint Display Manager (MDM). If startx triggers GUI login, then the DM is still on your system.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm aware that the DM (GDM in my case) is on my system. If it'd not be so, startx will not result in the graphic desktop launch.

Comment: So is your problem solved or do you still have a question (was startx the clue you needed)?  If it's solved, consider posting your own answer, which would be a help to others with a similar problem.  In another day, you will be able to accept the answer, which will indicate that the problem's been solved.

Comment: no, the problem is not solved and the question is displayed above

Comment: Your question isn't clear, then.  Q1: What starts the GUI is startx.  Q2: What pkg must be installed to enable GUI login is GDM.  Q3: The question says you can only login with text mode, but your comment indicates that GDM launches with startx.  Q4: Then it veers from the title and seems to talk about the problem being that you're getting a different DE.  It will be easier for people to help if you can clarify the question.

Comment: `startx` doesn't have anything to do with any DM. it's just a script that prepare certain stuff and then read your ~/.xinitrc or so and start a DE/WM, e.g. `cinnamon-session`; You don't need a specific DM for a specific DE either, nor you need a DM to be installed to use a DE with startx.